# Java Sockets: HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Tags: java, sockets, http

I'm creating a simple HTTP client. I followed a code example from [here](http://java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Socket/How_to_use_Java_Socket_class_to_create_a_HTTP_client.htm) which works for many sites except for [www.httbin.org](http://www.httbin.org). When I try [www.httbin.org](http://www.httbin.org) I get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy
Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 16:28:50 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I have looked at other SO answers but it hasn't helped.

Here is my code for testing this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Connection details
        InetAddress address =  InetAddress.getByName("www.httpbin.org");
        Socket mySocket = new Socket(address, 80);

        //Streams
        PrintWriter mySocketOutput = new PrintWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream());

        //Headers
        mySocketOutput.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");
        mySocketOutput.println("Host: www.httpbin.org");
        mySocketOutput.println("Connection: close");
        mySocketOutput.println();

        boolean loop = true;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        //reading results from server
        while (loop) {
            if(inputStreamReader.ready()) {
                int currentChar = 0;
                while (currentChar != -1) {
                    currentChar =  inputStreamReader.read();
                    stringBuilder.append((char) currentChar);
                }
                loop = false;
            }
        }

        //print result
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        mySocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you are making an HTTP/1.0 request to a server that only supports HTTP/1.1.

Comment: @JulianReschke: interesting guess but wrong. Even replacing `HTTP/1.0` with `HTTP/1.1` will not work - it needs instead `\r\n` instead of `\n` as line end (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your request looks similar to HTTP it is not. The line ending in HTTP according to the standard is `\r\n` and not a simple `\n` as you do with `println`. If using the proper line ending in all places (i.e. for each line with content but also for the "empty" line which ends the request header) it will work also with `www.httpbin.org`.

> HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Why this confusing answer from the server? Because your request has no proper delimiter between HTTP header and (the empty) HTTP body it is assumed to be a HTTP 0.9 request. The long obsolete [HTTP 0.9](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) protocol did not require an empty line consisting of only `\r\n` as end of request header since there were no such things as  header and body in HTTP 0.9 in the first place.

> I'm creating a simple HTTP client.

Please don't underestimate the complexity of writing a proper HTTP client. For example the code you've referenced as basis for your own client not only used the wrong line end for the request but also claimed to support HTTP/1.1 without being able to deal with chunked transfer encoding of the body.

And maybe you should skip the other code in this website too if you really want to learn  the protocols. At least the [Thin SMTP Client](http://java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Socket/How_to_use_Java_Socket_class_to_create_a_SMTP_Client.htm#A_Thin_SMTP_Client) also uses a broken protocol implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, I was able to fix the code. After reading the HTTP protocol, I do realize that it does require `CLRF ("\r\n")`.

I was wondering why did www.google.ca work with my current code, would you know? it works with `\n` only

Comment: @Rana: Many web servers deal with broken clients which use an improper line ending since enough self-made clients do not properly implement HTTP. But not all servers try to deal with such broken clients.